# Iphone application for parental control over browsing

Tags: ios, iphone, url, web

Here I am interested in developing an Iphone application which will check the outgoing URL form any browser,or at least from safari browser.

So how can I check user entered URL or user clicked URL. I want to perform some other actions depending on the URL clicked .

Is there any way to get the URL sending from the device or URL receiving to the device.??

what can be the best approach to develope parental control application to avoid child from browsing unwanted sites.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, app on iOS are sandboxed and can not just interact with other apps let alone change there behavior.

Comment: thanks but besides designing new browser is there any other way to warn user about site access.

Comment: Well unless you want to use a proxy server there is no other way. But to write your own browser.

Answer (score 0):

iOS already provides such functionality (Settings -> General -> Restrictions -> Websites). As stated before, third-party apps are sandboxed and may not access these system level functionality.

Comment: At least is there any way to edit inbuilt systems setting programmatically . As you said Settings -> General ->Restriction -> Websites is available to restrict websites can i reach to and edit or add those settings.

Comment: No, this is not possible (via a third-party app).